# How to reuse old speakers?

Tags: speakers

I am kinda interested in starting to learn something about electronics, I thought a good idea would be to try to reuse those speakers so here we are.

I see they have 2 wires but I don't know how could I connect them to let's say, a jack output, so I could plug it into my computer (if that's even possible)

I would thank any kind of guidance as my googling didn't help me much, thanks!

I Found them on the new flat so I don't have a idea of how they work, they seem to be DCM3020.
Is one cable for current and the other for data?
[image]
[image]

Comment: These speakers are generic 4-ohm speakers. They may be connected to an amplifier suitable for driving a four-ohm speaker load (**not** directly into a jack on a computer or smartphone). If you want to learn electronics, designing such an amplifier may be a worthwhile experiment. At the high school level, we indeed had such a project, where we first built a preamp using an op-amp, and then a class-A stage using power BJTs, for an acceptable level of audio quality.

Comment: *Is one cable for current and the other for data?* - no, but that question did make me smile. Good luck.

Comment: @B0nesh it is only one cable that contains two wires

Answer (score 3):

These appear to be plain speakers - no electronics in the box.

You would connect these to the output of a power amplifier.  You would not get enough signal from a computer "speaker" jack to make a useful amount of sound.

Comment: There may well be *some* electronics in the box; but it'll be limited to a simple passive filter aka "crossover" to split the signal into frequency bands for each drive unit.

Answer (score 2):

I am definitely more in the category of 'question asker' rather than 'question answerer' on this stack, almost everyone else posting answers knows way more than me so bear that in mind, but that said I am maybe only a few dozen projects and a year or two further than you in terms of hobbyist electronics so I'll share the thoughts I have had in my journey on the same question as it's still fresh fairly fresh in my mind.

An amp is actually a fairly difficult thing to get right, and to design something that performs as well as we would expect from a purchased bit of gear actually requires quite a few more components and considerations than you might expect.

As others have mentioned your speakers are just normal passive 4 ohm speakers (passive means 'no amp hidden inside the box', you need to amplify them externally, a clear indicator that you have active speakers is that theres a connection to plug them into the mains). The two wires are positive and negative. Essentially, the signal goes to positive and returns to the circuit via the negative. A speaker is essentially an electromagnet. When you put a positive voltage into it with the ability to provide a big enough current to excite the magnet then the speaker pulls one way, a negative voltage and it pulls the other way, and as such we can turn an electronic audio signal into a replication of that signal as movement back and forth from the speaker. Which creates the waves in air that we hear.

However to create that movement in what is often a fairly large magnet we need the signal to be strong enough, essentially in current but that current is generated by a voltage across the speaker coil's small resistance (4ohm in your case). The signal from a computer or phone won't be able to get a speaker to move all that much, and I'd be surprised if you could hear any sound from it at all. If you think about the only speakers (or really, drivers is the correct word here if we reserve the word speakers for things that are loud enough to fill a room with sound) that a phone is designed to power we get to headphones. Very tiny drivers that can only be heard if you put your ear right up to them, but thats fine, as it's how headphones are designed to be used.

So we need quite a lot of power to drive even a modest set of speakers, requiring an amp to amplify the computer/phone signal to the point where it can power the speakers sufficiently. Thats where things get complex, because designing an amp requires a lot of knowledge, you cant just take one component, like a transistor, and set it up to amplify and expect to get good results, you may amplify the signal quite a bit, but it won't be enough to generate a movement, or the impedance is all wrong so you are loosing your amplified signal over a resistor in the output stage, or it will be massively distorted etc. etc.

There are basically (and this is where others more knowledgeable will be able to point out my lack of knowledge) a few different ways to amplify. Vacuum tubes are fairly easy to understand and their circuits are relatively simple, BUT you need EXTREMELY high, VERY dangerous (500v+ is normal), voltages (and a power circuit to create those voltages) and at those voltages you have to design the physical placement of parts in the amp very carefully to avoid huge hums and so on, and you still need quite a few parts costing a LOT more than modern alternatives. But that said, you can buy kits and slowly build them if you are up for the challenge but you have to be VERY CAREFUL, as the voltages really are astronomical inside the amp, I would triple check that you have read everything you can find on electrical safety and see if you understand and are fine with all the warnings before you even CONSIDER such a project. To be honest, for a fun DIY project I would say don't even go near, but if you are really into that stuff (as I am) then you CAN learn it, but take it a millimeter at a time. I really include tubes here just for historical audio amp completeness!

The other ways of amplifying are semiconductor based, a type of material that replaced the need for vacuum tubes, transistors basically in this case.

There are a few forms of transistors. BJT's are a type can be arranged to make very good audio amps, but you can't just use one, a normal BJT based amp will have a dozen or so transistors doing complicated things to convert current to voltage and voltage to current, creating correct impedance between stages, slowly stepping up the signal and finally preparing it to power the speaker. As you go through the amp the voltages/currents get higher and basically much of the amp is preparing the signal to be fed to the 'final stage', a pair of transistors that can happily deal with the power needed and have to be mounted to heatsinks and so on.

Other ways of amplifying are fet transistors, and opamps.

Fet's play a part, and can actually be a very fun and easy way to simply amplify a signal a bit without too much hassle or complex circuits, but really only for smaller signals, still not enough to power a speaker. Some fets make their way into high quality amplifiers and I have a schematic for a great MOSFET (a further subtype of fet) hifi amp that I am meaning to build someday.

Opamps are a clever little amazing device in a tiny IC (ie. microchip), and very simple to use as an amp. They are basically a combination of transistors in a classic configuration held on a single IC. They are not really any good as power amplifiers, as they just can't work at power levels high enough to power a speaker. They're not designed for that sort of application anyway, but they certainly can play a part in 'preamplifying' a signal, that is taking the smallest initial signal and boosting it for the next stage.

So far though, no help to your project! As mentioned, transistors arranged as an audio power amp is a complicated circuit that will require much study to understand the different circuit subsets involved and what they are doing. A basic circuit using transistors (bjt's in this case) was kind of worked out several decades ago and it's basic arrangement has found it's way into MANY commercial amps both hi-fi and instrument. It's called a Lin Amp (not to be confused with Linn the audio amp company), it's basically a circuit designed (like most) in logical blocks or stages, and you can scale it up and it works as a guitar amp or similar, or scale it down and put it on an IC. It's basically a tried and tested version of the complicated bjt based amp I was alluding to above, and most of the transistor based hifi and guitar amps I have worked on follow roughly the lin topology.

So, you can buy what is roughly a lin amp (with a few alterations here or there as always) as an IC, called an lm386. This is perhaps a good foray into the very first dabblings with audio amps. It's a lin topology on a very very cheap IC thats a little like an op amp but tweaked for audio amp use. You can buy lm386 amp modules on ebay for £3 or similar, which is a pcb and the IC and the other parts needed (IC's need other components as well to work). It will give you a chance to learn about the other components needed, PCB's and soldering and getting the audio in and out of the circuit. They are very small, can be powered from a 9v battery, and if you solder something wrong or blow the IC it's pennies to replace a part more or less. I don't think an lm386 would really do anything at all with your large speakers, you'd probably hear the speaker trying to move a TINY bit, but it would distort like hell and max out way before it got to a useable volume, but plug it into a little speaker you may have and you would hear it in all it's distorted and crappy but WORKING glory! (with luck).

If you can get an lm386 board working and have used it to learn a bunch of stuff like powering the IC and power supply smoothing caps, controlling an IC's 'options' by placing a certain component across two pins and basic differences some component choices make the you may be keen to step it up. These days you can get many larger versions of the lm386 style thing that handle a lot more power, they may need a heatsink or more voltage but once you understand an lm386 circuit you won't be daunted by stepping it up so much, and learning new concepts along the way. Thats probably the gentle-est way 'in'. They still may not sound amazing, but it's a more agreeable learning curve than trying to make a whole, discreet (meaning no IC's, all the parts you are using are individual parts) amplifier from scratch. If I had a teacher who could work with me I'd probably have started with a somewhat more ambitious project, but getting a cheap lm386 amp to work on my own was a great starting point if theres no other option.

It's worth noting often the trickiest consideration with a project is not the circuit itself, it's how you are going to POWER it, plugging it into the wall instantly requires a whole lot more knowledge to make a useable power rail and not blow something, or yourself, up. Along with many other parts needed, some scary to use at first. Multi voltage wall-wart style plugs are useful but they don't give out the cleanest of power, but that can be a reason to learn about how smoothing caps work! Or if you really get into it you can buy a bench power supply (or build one) or learn about other parts such as voltage regulators.

Another other option is to buy a kit amp, you won't learn so much about the circuit and how it's working but you will learn a TONNE about correct component placement, soldering and probably troubleshooting. Troubleshooting is gonna be the biggest friend for a while whilst learning these endeavours and it can be incredibly frustrating at times, but I would say it's very worth it! After destroying a few £3 amp modules or their IC's you will start to get the hang of it and after a while it's an incredibly rewarding and endlessly fascinating hobby. Later still you can start fixing or making cool things for very little money, and you can trickle learn the theory as you go. It's kept me sane in this last year or so, along with posting long rambling potentially inaccurate posts on social media too, of course!

Answer (score 1):

> Is one cable for current and the other for data?

No -- that would imply a DAC and an amplifier inside the box.

Your computer audio jack outputs stereo analog audio (probably).  You need to amplify it with an audio amplifier, and feed the output of that to your speakers.

Kinda-basic electronics would be to get an amplifier kit, build it, and try it.  *Really* basic electronics would be to get an amplifier module, hook it up to power and your computer, and try it.